# Number Pattern cutoff

Tags: java, design-patterns, numbers

```
public class numPattern {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int digit1 = 2;
        int digit2 = 7;
        int    tal = 0;

        System.out.print(digit1 + " ");
        System.out.print(digit2 + " ");

        while (tal < 550) {
            tal = digit1 + digit2;

            System.out.print(tal + " ");

            digit1 = digit2;
            digit2 = tal;
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs `2, 7, 9, 16, 25, 41, 66......453 and 733`

The issue is it should stop at 453 because 733 is way over 550.

What command would make sure the program ends at 453 to meet the the greater or equal to 550 I'm trying to seek?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple change :

```
while (tal < 550){
    tal = digit1 + digit2;

    System.out.print(tal + " ");
    digit1 = digit2;
    digit2 = tal;
}
```

to:

```
while (tal < 550) {
    System.out.print(tal + " ");

    digit1 = digit2;
    digit2 = tal;
    tal = digit1 + digit2;
}
```

and the initialization of `tal` : 
from `int tal = 0` , to `int tal = digit1 + digit2;`

Comment: This prints "2 7 ***0*** 9 16 25 41 66 107 173 280 453 " (i.e. there i an extra "0" printed out as the first number)

Comment: Would a if statement be a way to fix this?

Comment: To fix what? The 0 in the middle of the sequence?

Comment: Well, the tal has to be set to 0 and because there is a while statement, would putting a if statement with something like if (tal =< 500) be better? I know in C++ the would be one way, but in Java I'm not to sure.

Comment: i don't understand actually. WHy does tal HAVE TO be set to 0? you print `digit1` and `digit2` outside your loop. Thats why tal has to start at `digit1 + digit2`. I don't understand what your problem is actually. Have you done the changes i suggested? Because they actually work

Answer (score 3):

Increase the value of `tal` in the `while`:

```
    int digit1 = 2;
    int digit2 = 7;
    int tal = 0;

    System.out.print(digit1 + " ");
    System.out.print(digit2 + " ");

    while((tal = digit1 + digit2)< 550)
    {

        System.out.print(tal + " ");

        digit1 = digit2;
        digit2 = tal;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just skip the printout of `digit2`, initialize `tal` to the same value, and reorder the statements in your loop:

```
int digit1 = 2;
System.out.print(digit1 + " ");

int digit2 = 7;
int tal = digit2;
while (tal < 550) {
    System.out.print(tal + " ");
    tal = digit1 + digit2;
    digit1 = digit2;
    digit2 = tal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 int digit1 = 2;

 System.out.print(digit1 + " "); //it will print digit1
do not print digit2

int digit2 = 7;
int tal = digit2;
while (tal < 550) {
    System.out.print(tal + " ");
    tal = digit1 + digit2;
    digit1 = digit2;
    digit2 = tal;
}
```

Because in your loop it first increases the value and then prints it so before the condition says false it already prints the value  when tal = 443 then it enters the while loop does the sum and prints it and then go to check the value

After reordring it first prints the value then do the sum and check if its less or not and thus it will not proceed after 443

Comment: This prints "2 7 ***0*** 9 16 25 41 66 107 173 280 453 " (i.e. there i an extra "0" printed out as the first number)